# Is there a 1-value "class wrapper" type in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, class, struct, wrapper

I am dealing with an existing custom collection type. The constraint cannot be changed at this time.

```
class CustomDict<TKey, TValue>
where TValue : class
```

I would like to use a structure type (ie. `bool`) as the value.

Is there a *standard* .NET/CLR type that can be used as a class-around-struct wrapper, such that the following is valid?

```
new CustomDict<string, Wrapper<bool>>(..)
```

Implicit/explicit conversions would be neat, but are not a requirement. It would, of course, be trivial to create a custom class - the question is about [re]using a common/core class type.

Comment: Oh, ayaahahah! Free points.. SO works well as an armchair.

Comment: The question is **why** that constraint was added. it is super-easy to make a class that wraps a value-type, but what would it have to provide in order to satisfy this odd requirement?

Comment: *It would, of course, be trivial to create a custom class* I'd probably just do that.

Comment: You've probably spent 2 orders of magnitude more time writing this question than it would have taken you to write your own solution.

Comment: @Servy And it would have been silly to write my own solution in this case. The free points were to use `Tuple<N>`.

Comment: @user2864740 It would have been dumb to spend dramatically less time to get a superior result, and also not waste the time of lots of other people to get that quicker and better result?  Why would that be dumb?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen "Decisions made a long, long time ago". I have no current valid justification for why it ended up that way and this code is .. going on over a decade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this `Tuple` class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

You can use a `Tuple<bool>` for the `TValue` type parameter. Just call `Create` to create an instance e.g.:

```
Tuple.Create(true)
```

Comment: A good answer, but personally I think I'd rather take the 30 seconds it takes to whip together a custom class just to avoid the really ugly `Item1` property to access the value in the `Tuple`.

Comment: @MattBurland I agree. I am also sure that OP is aware of creating a custom class, he probably has some reason for not doing so.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for - I typed `Tuple1` into C# and missed `Tuple<..>` until a web search a minute later (I also had the wrong idea that Tuples were value types, which is why I eventually ended up on MSDN to begin with)! This is a localized use-case that doesn't bleed beyond private methods.

Answer (score 2):

As you stated yourself, it's trivially easy to do. For example:

```
public class StructWrapper<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    public StructWrapper(T val)
    {
        Value = val;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(StructWrapper<T> w)
    {
        return w.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator StructWrapper<T>(T s)
    {
        return new StructWrapper<T>(s);
    }
}
```

Then you could do something like:

```
var bw = new StructWrapper<bool>(true);
```

And because of the implicit conversions, you can do stuff like:

```
if (bw)
{
    Console.WriteLine("True!");
}
```

And it should work.

If you need / want to implement equality, you could add this to `StructWrapper<T>`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is StructWrapper<T>) 
    {
        return Value.Equals(((StructWrapper<T>)obj).Value);
    }
    return Value.Equals(obj);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Value.GetHashCode();
}

public static bool operator ==(StructWrapper<T> a, StructWrapper<T> b)
{
    if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return a.Value.Equals(b.Value);
}

public static bool operator !=(StructWrapper<T> a, StructWrapper<T> b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}

public static bool operator ==(StructWrapper<T> a, T b)
{
    return a.Value.Equals(b);
}

public static bool operator !=(StructWrapper<T> a, T b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}

public static bool operator ==(T b, StructWrapper<T> a)
{
    return a.Value.Equals(b);
}

public static bool operator !=(T b, StructWrapper<T> a)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

Which would let you do something like this:

```
var isbwTrue = bw == true;
```

Comment: While I'm using Tuple<N> in this specific case, there are definitely situations in which a wrapper would be cleaner. However, this also illustrates the problem of adding one-off code: it does not correctly implement Equality (over the wrapped value) which would break the usage here. The existing Tuple types do.

Comment: This is wrapping a struct in a class. As for equality, you can certainly implement that if you want to

Comment: The question clearly asks about reusing an existing type, not how to implement one:
"It would, of course, be trivial to create a custom class - the question is about [re]using a common/core class type."